# Cacti alias on Nginx

Tags: nginx, cacti

I am trying to run Cacti on Nginx as alias, however it returns 404 when I set the correct alias path.

The strange thing is that if I set another path it loads the files.
  Cacti path is `/usr/share/cacti/site` which returns 404, if I try with `/usr/share/cacti` I got a list with the directories.

Here is my config -

```
server {
    #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name domain.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;
    }

    location /cacti {
            autoindex on;
            alias /usr/share/cacti/site;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
                    location ~ \.php$ {
                            try_files $uri =404;
                            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                            fastcgi_index index.php;
                            #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$request_filename;
                            include fastcgi_params;
                            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share$request_filename;
                    }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `root` for cacto location, I guess using `alias` is the root cause of your 404, since `$document_root` refers to `root`. I'm sure error_log holds more clues.

Comment: But I want to use it as an alias, I don't want to have separate domain/subdomain just for cacti.
What I mean is want to access from `domain.com/cacti`. That way I can access either with the IP or the domain name.
And root shouldn't be important as I might want to add it to another server block with different root.
error_log doesn't show nothing for this case, if I use wrong path for alias it shows which file is not found, but in this scenario is empty.
Anyway, after few hours battling with it, I decided it is far easier to use subdomain rather trying to make it work like this.